# What does the error "should check the method return value" mean?

Tags: java, swing

I am writing an application in Java using Swing. I am trying to convert the value in the text field `txtDay` to uppercase before evaluating the value in the below switch statement.

```
txtDay.getText().toUpperCase();

switch(txtDay.getText()){
    case "SUNDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "MONDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "TUESDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "WEDNESDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "THURSDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "FRIDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    case "SATURDAY":
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        //do something
        break;
}
```

Though at the first line (`txtDay.getText().toUpperCase()`), I am receiving an error saying "Should check the method return value".

What does this mean? Any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: Always have a default case in a switch, unless you are switching on an enum. In this case I would have a default that throws a RuntimeException with a sensible message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an error but a warning. It says that you are not using the result of the operation. Strings being immutable, you need something like:

```
txtDay.setText(txtDay.getText().toUpperCase());
```

to get the result you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
txtDay.getText().toUpperCase();
```

to

```
txtDay.setText(txtDay.getText().toUpperCase());
```

Strings are **immutable** in Java. Which means `txtDay.getText().toUpperCase();` won't actually change the value of your `txtDay` component.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this warning because `txtDay.getText().toUpperCase()` is returning a `String`, but you are not using the returned value.

To achieve what you are looking for, you need to set the text field to the returned value from `txtDay.getText().toUpperCase()` like so...

```
txtDay.setText(txtDay.getText().toUpperCase());
```